# I have three radio buttons in one cell in tablesorter

Tags: tablesorter

I have three radio buttons in one cell in tablesorter.
How can I filter by each value?
I have been trying for several days looking at the official site but cannot solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "radio" parser inside [`parser-input-select`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js) as follows ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ehzs5uat/)):

```
<th class="sorter-radio">Appointment status</th>
```

then initialize normally

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    debug: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It worked correctly, thanks for the demo too!